# How to pass a result from one then() block to the next then() block in a JavaScript Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios

I want to make 2 MySQL queries from one GET request, knit the results together and return them.  But I'm having difficulty passing the result of the first query to the next then() block.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const con = require('../../db');

router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
axios.get('/').then(docs => { //get one book by its id number
    const sql = "SELECT title, line, mage_edition FROM books WHERE id=" + req.params.id;
    con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        return result; //"result" shows proper value here
    });
}).then(docs => { //get all the listings that appear inside that book
    //How do I get "result" here?
    const sql2 = "SELECT l.entry_id, e.title, e.kind, e.sort FROM links l INNER JOIN entries e ON l.entry_id = e.id WHERE book_id=" + req.params.id;
    con.query(sql2, (err, result2) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        //combine result and result2, then give back with res.status(200).json()
    })
});
});
module.exports = router;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I finished a training video series on asynchronous JavaScript but I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Slightly related: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: I know your question is about chaining promises, but in this case there is no need, you could get all the information from the database with just one SQL statement.

Comment: trincot, in most situations this would be excellent advice. In my case the 2 query results are so different it would take more time than it's worth to "normalize" the columns to combine the queries and additional work to make sense of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your query call doesn't return a promise, it just calls the callback when it's done. If whatever database library you're using doesn't support returning promises, I'd suggest creating wrapper functions for your query methods that return a promise instead. It'll make chaining them into promises much easier.

Something like this:

```
function queryPromise(con, sql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { return reject(err); }
        return resolve(result);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Or use util.promisify since the structure of the callback is `(err, result) => { ... }`: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Comment: ^ That's an option, too. Though to be fair, that util function probably does the same thing internally, or something very similar :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me see what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

To return from one `.then` to next `.then` you should return the value from `previous` then. Your code is not working because you are returning your result from a callback function. You can't return value from callback function.

Check if your `.query` function returns any promise or not. If yes then you should do something like this `const result = awati con.query(sql);`.

Or, you can promisify your `.query` function and then await it.

Answer (score 0):

use the `return` key word to return the result within the `then()` block. This should m are the data available for the next block.

Bear in mind that if you need an in-order execution of the then blocks, you would need to return a Promise instead of resolved values